# DurandalJS Routing Behavior

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

**What I Have**

Trying to understand what's going on and how to control it.  I have a "public" view for users that have not yet been authenticated, and a "home" view for users that are authenticated.  Here's my route config:

```
app.start().then(function() {
        //Replace 'viewmodels' in the moduleId with 'views' to locate the view.
        //Look for partial views in a 'views' folder in the root.
        viewLocator.useConvention();

        //configure routing
        router.useConvention();

        router.mapRoute('home', 'viewmodels/home', 'Test App', true);
        router.mapRoute('public', 'viewmodels/public', 'Test App', true);
        router.mapRoute('set/:id', 'viewmodels/set', 'Set');
        router.mapRoute('folder/:id', 'viewmodels/folder', 'Folder');
        router.mapRoute('api', 'viewmodels/api', 'API Reference');
        router.mapRoute('error', 'viewmodels/error', 'Error', false);
        app.adaptToDevice();

        //Show the app by setting the root view model for our application with a transition.

        if (dataservice.isAuthenticated() === true) {
            app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
            router.navigateTo('home');
        } else {
            app.setRoot('viewmodels/public');
            router.navigateTo('#/public');
        }

        router.handleInvalidRoute = function (route, params) {
            logger.logError('No route found', route, 'main', true);
            router.navigateTo('#/error');
        };
    });
```

**The Problems**

When I run the app for the first time, I'm not authenticated, and I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lookupRoute' of undefined
```

Originating from the `'router.navigateTo('#/public');'` line.

Then when I try to click the login button, I get the same error from this:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/dataservice'], function (app, router, dataservice) {
   var publicViewModel = function () {
        self.logIn = function () {
            app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell');
            router.navigateTo('#/home');
        };
```

But the content loads correctly.  When I navigate to a particular page by clicking, say to /folder/2, and then change the url to /folders/2 (invalid), I get "route not found" in my log, as expected, but I run into a few other issues:

1. I don't get the error page, or any errors (as I think I should, per my handleInvalidRoute)
2. If I click on something else, the url doesn't change, and new content isn't loaded, again with no errors.

I think I'm breaking routing somehow, but I'm not sure how.  How can I correct the above issues?

Screen:

[image]

Comment: Is anything showing in your javascript console? - durandal is very good in my experience in telling you what might be going wrong

Comment: Thanks again mutex.  I updated my code and description - I'm now getting some errors related to routing but can't quite figure out what's up :/

Comment: what does your public.js viewmodel look like? Does it have a router?

Comment: Updated my code sample to show how I'm pulling it in - I just specify the router in the 'define' statement.  Is that right?

Comment: I'm rather new to DurandalJS. I'm looking for a way to authenticate a user. Could you please explain how does dataservice.isAuthenticated() works? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect calling navigateTo where you are might be too soon for some reason.  To test this theory try move this code.

```
    if (dataservice.isAuthenticated() === true) {
        app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
        router.navigateTo('home');
    } else {
        app.setRoot('viewmodels/public');
        router.navigateTo('#/public');
    }
```

into an "activate" method on your publicviewmodel, and in the main.js just leave this:

```
app.setRoot('viewmodels/public');
```

**EDIT: Old suggestion**

I believe on your viewmodel for the root you need a router property. So modify your public viewmodel to add one:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/dataservice'], function (app, router, dataservice) {
   var publicViewModel = function () {
        self.router = router;
        self.logIn = function () {
            app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell');
            router.navigateTo('#/home');
        };
```

(where do you define self though?)

Comment: I'm defining self in there, I just took it out accidentally when I pulled all of the other methods out. I tried your suggestion and it didn't work... still getting the router errors.  I dig into it and it looks like it's somehow related to sammy?  Updated my post.

Comment: I don't know if I did this correctly, but I added the if/else right after the publicViewModel definition (after the closing curly) and I still get the same error.. not sure if that's what you meant by activate.

Comment: sorry by activate I mean a method on the viewmodel literally called activate. durandal will call this for you.  So you would have self.activate = function() { /*If else in here*/ }; on the viewmodel

Comment: I added just the if statement (the else was giving me an infinite loop) to the activate method and now when I load the app, no errors are thrown and the correct page is displayed.  But when I click "logIn", the navigateTo returns the same error.  I'll play with this and post a more specific question if I can't figure it out; thanks again :)

Comment: Glad it helped. To me having multiple "app.setRoot" calls through the app smells a bit bad, I'd maybe try and refactor to avoid that.